# Need correction or suggestion over javascript that calculate difference in between two dates

Tags: javascript, html, difference

#### Age Calculations

I collect this JavaScript from many website; I would like to get age in between two different dates;
in this script or example I’m looking to show my daughter **age**;; Everything goes fine  *until her age passes 6 month*,
The script rounds the age to the upper number which is 
**(ONE year in this case)** , and 
round down the month which shows months digit in minus.
Well, I would like the script to view years rounded to the lower number if it’s ***less than 365 days***,
and months to be ***rounded up since the days less than 365 days***.

```html
<!-- Calculate Age -->
<script type="text/javascript">
var s = '2016-01-31T17:17:28.593Z';
var a = s.split(/[^0-9]/);
var d=new Date (a[0],a[1]-1,a[2],a[3],a[4],a[5] );
var fromDate = new Date(d);
var toDate = new Date();

// current date format as mm-dd-yyyy 
    var Start_Date = new Date(d);
    var sec = Start_Date.getSeconds();
    var min = Start_Date.getMinutes();
    var hr = Start_Date.getHours();
    var dd = Start_Date.getDate();
    var mm = Start_Date.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
    var yyyy = Start_Date.getFullYear();
 if(dd<10){
   dd='0'+dd
  } 
 if(mm<10){
   mm='0'+mm
  }
 if(hr<10){
   hr='0'+hr
  }
 if(min<10){
   min='0'+min
  }
var Start_Date = dd+'-'+mm+'-'+yyyy+'&nbsp at <span style="direction:ltr; color:red ;font-weight:700;">[&nbsp'+hr+ ":" +min+ ":" +sec+'&nbsp]</span>';
// End date format as mm-dd-yyyy
// Start_Date = str;
var differenceTravel = toDate.getTime() - fromDate.getTime();
// var months = Math.ceil (toDate.getMonth() - fromDate.getMonth() + (12 * (toDate.getFullYear() - 
// 1 day = 86400000,
var Tyears = Math.round(differenceTravel/1000/60/60/24/365);
var Tmonths = Math.round((differenceTravel - (Tyears * 365*60*60*24*1000)) / (1000*60*60*24*30));
var Tdays = Math.round((differenceTravel - (Tyears *60*60*24*365*1000) - (Tmonths *60*60*24*30*1000))/ (86400000));
//
document.writeln('<div style="color:Blue">');
document.writeln('<ul>');
document.writeln('<li><span style="color:Navy">Seba Birthday:&nbsp;</span> ' + Start_Date +'</li>');
document.write('<li><span style="color:MediumVioletRed">Her age is:</span>&nbsp; '+ Tyears +'<span style="color:Green">&nbsp;year &nbsp; and &nbsp; </span>'+ Tmonths +'<span style="color:Green">&nbsp;months &nbsp; and &nbsp;</span>'+ Tdays +'<span style="color:Green">&nbsp;days</span></li>');
document.writeln('</ul></div>');
</script>
<!-- / good -->
```

Comment: don't `Math.round` - use `Math.floor` for a start

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">  
var Birth_Date = new Date('2016-04-27');  
  
document.writeln(Birth_Date.getDate()+ "-" +Birth_Date.getMonth()+1 + "-" + Birth_Date.getFullYear());  
</script>`
  
    In this example the browser shows incorrect date;  
    While if I change the date to be:  
`var Birth_Date = new Date('2016-01-31');`
    It show correct date,  
    __Is that bug;__  

    _How to correct it;_

Comment: No it is not an error - your code is in error ... `Birth_Date.getDate()+ "-" +(Birth_Date.getMonth()+1) + "-" + Birth_Date.getFullYear()` - `()` around the month + 1 will fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to round down, use [Math.floor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor), not `Math.round`, which will round up or down depending on if the value is `<` or `>` than `0.5`.

Answer (score 0):

Change these three lines:

```
var Tyears = Math.round(differenceTravel/1000/60/60/24/365);
var Tmonths = Math.round((differenceTravel - (Tyears * 365*60*60*24*1000)) / (1000*60*60*24*30));
var Tdays = Math.round((differenceTravel - (Tyears *60*60*24*365*1000) - (Tmonths *60*60*24*30*1000))/ (86400000));
```

To the following:

```
var Tyears = Math.floor(differenceTravel/1000/60/60/24/365);
var Tmonths = Math.ceil((differenceTravel - (Tyears * 365*60*60*24*1000)) / (1000*60*60*24*30));
var Tdays = Math.round((differenceTravel - (Tyears *60*60*24*365*1000) - (Tmonths *60*60*24*30*1000))/ (86400000));
```